Linear dependence of transformations
Assume that I have matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ and vector column variable $R \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I split their row  into two subsets: $B_0$ and $R_0$ having $d$ rows and $B_1$ and $R_1$ having $n_1 = n -d$ rows. Then I form vector $Y$ as $Y=R_1 - B_1 B_0^{-1} R_0$. I need to show that vectors $Y$ obtained for different splits of $B$ and $R$ are linearly dependent.
Here is a more formal formulation of the problem. Let $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ be rank-$d$ matrix with $d < n$. Let $n_1=n-d$. Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ of size $n\times n$ be two permutation matrices. Let $P_i = (P_{i1}, P_{i2})^T$ with $P_{i1}\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$ and $P_{i2}\in \mathbb{R}^{n_1\times n}$, $i=1,2$.
Let vector valued functions $Y_i$ be defines as
$$Y_i(R) = -P_{i2} B (P_{i1} B ) ^{-1} P_{i1} R + P_{i2} R, i=1, 2$$
for $n$-sized vector $R$.
I see empirically for various examples that there exists a matrix $C$, independent of $R$, such that $Y_1(R) = C Y_2(R)$. I struggle to prove it for a general case.
Intuitively it looks like a particular case of something simple and well known. Could someone point me to something?
A few thoughts on the solution I have so far.
We can formulate $Y$s as linear transformations of $R$. In particular,
$$Y_i = A_i R$$
with
$$
A_i = \begin{bmatrix} -P_{i2} B (P_{i1} B ) ^{-1} & I_{n_1\times n_1}\end{bmatrix} P_i.
$$
If matrix $C$ I'm looking for exists, it can be written as $C = \hat A_1 \hat A_2 ^{-1}$ with $\hat A_i$ being left $n_1 \times n_1$ submatrix of $A_i$. Empirically this is the case but I need to prove formally that $A_1 = C A_2$.
I managed to prove it for the case when $P_{11}$ and $P_{21}$ define non-intersecting  subsets. Assuming for simplicity that $P_{11}$ is identity and $P_{21}$ moves rows $d+1, \dots, 2d$ to the first place and $B_{11}$ is matrix, comprised of rows $2d+1,\dots, n$ of matrix $B$, matrix
\begin{equation}
C = 
\begin{bmatrix} -P_{11}B(P_{21}B)^{-1} & 0 \\ B_{11}(P_{11}B)^{-1} & I_{(n_1-d) \times (n_1-d)} \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
works. If $n_1>d$ I could make other cases a chain of non-intersecting transformations. But it doesn't work if $n_1 < d$ so general proof is still needed.
